# Activate HTML tags in Textarea from which a pdf is generated

Tags: php, html, tinymce, pdf-generation, decode

How can I activate html tags in a textarea so that they are applied in a generated pdf?

I've tried this:

```
<textarea name="letter">'.html_entity_decode($letter).'</textarea>
```

..without success.

**The content of my textarea looks like this:**

```
<h1>Test<h2>
<h2>Test2<h2>
<a href="www.google.de">Google</a>
```

**The generated PDF looks like this (nothing changed):**

```
<h1>Test<h2>
<h2>Test2<h2>
<a href="www.google.de">Google</a>
```

The PDF-Generator outputs it like this:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(175,5, stripslashes(html_entity_decode($letter)), 0, 'L', 0);
```

I have inserted html_entity_decode anywhere, but it just does not work..

A TinyMCE editor is used, but the system is so old and complex that I do not understand how everything works together.

A temporary solution would suffice for me because there will soon be a new system based on angularjs and laravel.

Hope you can help..

Comment: I'm guessing you actually want to HTML *encode* that content--try htmlentities($letter) instead.

Comment: Yup.. For example, I would like an a-tag to be interpreted in the generated PDF

Comment: If you just append $letter (and for the sake of the test, make sure it doesn't contain any html special chars) do you see it correctly in your PDF? Now if you just replace $letter with an `<a href='test'>test</a>`, do you get a link in your PDF?

If so, and if $letter contains valid HTML already...why encode or decode it at all? Does $letter already contain *escaped* HTML?

Comment: I've updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using content editable div with border like a text area.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black" contentEditable="true">
    <span>Hello ! this is test div</span>
</div>
```